# Using conditional formatting in cells where IF AND Fomula has been used

Tags: excel

I've been struggling with trying to apply conditional formatting to a range of potential values in a cell that is populated with an IF/AND Formula.

I have the following formula in Cell `G3: =IF(AND(E3="Inj",F3="Lim"),"4","")&IF(E3="No Acc","1","")&IF(AND(E3="Inj",F3="Min"),"20","")...`

The actual formula is larger than this with 20 of the IF/AND Formula in the cell.

I end up with a number output in `G3`. I want the 17 potential number outputs to be associated with either Green, Yellow, Orange or Red (Cell Fill Colour). I've tried with conditional formatting in a variety of ways but can't get it to work at all. The number/colour associations are as follows: 12500, 2503, 2500 = Red. 503, 502, 500 = Orange. 250, 102, 101, 100, 50, 21, 20 = Yellow. 10, 4, 2, 1 = Green

Some help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are the numbers to be assigned to the fill colors?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for quick response. There are actually 17 possible numbers (sorry said 20 earlier) but it is a 20 box matrix. Number/colour assignment would be as follows: 12500, 2503, 2500 = Red. 503, 502, 500 = Orange. 250, 102, 101, 100, 50, 21, 20 = Yellow. 10, 4, 2, 1 = Green. Thank you

Comment: Best to update your question if you want to add details - easier to read there...

Comment: I would use a formula-based CF rule for each color.

Comment: Thanks Tim. How would that work? I tried some but couldn't get it to work properly

Comment: `=G3>1000` (for example) as the first rule, with red fill and "stop if true", followed by similar rules for the other colors

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your help with this. I've only just got back to it and what you've suggested I've been using but I don't think its working because the conditional formatting formula is recognising the numbers in the formula rather than the result. Is there a function I can use on the formula to make it work as an absolute number with the conditional formatting? Thank you Ollie

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4 formula-based CF rules as shown below (I did not enter all of the numbers you provided)

First one (red fill) is:

```
=OR(A1=12500,A1=2503,A1=2500)
```

The other 3 follow the same pattern.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. With the use of your formatting and adding =NUMBERVALUE() to the start of the formula it worked